# How to compute 2D inverse stationary wavelet transform at each scale level separately?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, wavelet

For example, I'd like to apply the transform four times on an image and then perform the inverse transform on each scale's subimages set at a time, because I do some processing in certain scales, but I don't in the others. So, with MATLAB function, when I give it all the images from all scales, it reconstructs the original image, but when I give it only the subimages from the scale 4, for example, the result is not equal to the LL subimage from scale 3 obtained with the forward transform. Illustrating it, what I'd like is something like (`I` is the matrix corresponding to the image):

```
[A,H,V,D] = swt2(I,4,'db4');
I3 = iswt2(A(:,:,4), H(:,:,4), V(:,:,4), D(:,:,4),'db4');
I2 = iswt2(I3, H(:,:,3), V(:,:,3), D(:,:,3),'db4');
I1 = iswt2(I2, H(:,:,2), V(:,:,2), D(:,:,2),'db4');
Ir = iswt2(I1, H(:,:,1), V(:,:,1), D(:,:,1),'db4');
```

The problem is that `I3` is not equal to `A(:,:,3)`, for example, which doesn't allow me to reconstruct the image level by level.

How could I do that using the MATLAB functions?

Comment: You can type `open iswt2` in console and debug the code to see where it goes wrong. I think `iswt2` is optimised for taking a conplete set of decomposed data. You will probably have to copy the code to your working path and modify it.

Comment: I did something like that, but the problem is that I don't unsderstand very well how the M

Comment: I did something like that, but the problem is that I don't unsderstand very well how the MATLAB function works. Forward and inverse transforms have very different implementations and although I understand the forward transform's code, I don't the inverse one. What I have also noticed is that the inverse transform doesn't reconstruct an image scale by scale. Actually it uses a loop _for_ to do so, but the intermediate images generated don't correspond to the subimages generated in the forward transform.